# Is there any way to design my Java code so these two objects don't reference themselves?

Tags: java, design-patterns, composition

**The Setup**

My Java code contains two objects: a Group and a Person. Each Group can contain references to multiple Person's, but each Person can only belong to one Group.

The colour of each Person's sweatshirt is derived from their Group's colour. (Note: If they don't belong to a Group, their sweater is gray.)

When I draw a Person on-screen, I take in the Person themselves and a Color.

**The Code**

*Person*

```
public class Person {
    Color sweatshirtColor = Color.gray;
    Group belongsToGroup = null;

    public void setGroup(Group g) { belongsToGroup = g; }
}
```

*Group*

```
public class Group {
    Color color = Color.red;
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    // ... setters for adding and getting people
}
```

*Draw*

```
public void draw(Person dudette, Color shirtColor) { //... }
```

**The Problem**
Group and Person both reference each other - I'm afraid that one might get out of sync with the other. My draw code has to be fixed (because it's external), but is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong in this design?

EDIT: One more note - Groups can change throughout the program. A Person's Group depends on their location so they are constantly switching Groups.

Comment: Did you try with ThreadLocal ?

Comment: Are these objects being populated from the database? The problem with syncing can be solved with the Identity Map Pattern. So you'll have just one instance of each object.

Comment: I think these are overkill for my intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could introduce setters to each class that will allow either entity to modify the other and itself so that they never get out of synch. E.g.

```
class Group {
    List<Person> people;
    void removePerson(Person p) {
        if(people.remove(p))
            p.removeFromGroup();
    }
}

class Person {
    Group grp;
    void removeFromGroup() {
        grp.removePerson(this);
        grp = null;
    }
}
```

You can do the same for adding group members.

Comment: This is attractive to me - I'm just considering the other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting the list of persons from a group, i.e. are you actually invoking `Group#getPeople()` in your code? Then you you'll need the bidirectional connection between the two classes, as you also use the connection from `Person` to `Group` to obtain the t-shirt color. If you don't use `getPeople()`, there is no need to keep a list of people in group and then the connection from `Group` to `Person` would be unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, I do need to use getPeople().

Answer (score 1):

One way to not storing the container (Group) in Person is to make Person an inner class of Group, In fact that is the primary goal of inner classes.

```
public class Group {

    public Person createPerson() { ... }

    public class Person {
        private Person() { ... }
        ...
            Group.this
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make too much sense for my usage because there are other things a person can belong to (other than a Group). But it's a good answer if I only had one "group".

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Group's public methods to add/remove people must update Person's references to Group and vice versa:

```
public class Person {
    public static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.GRAY;

    private Group group;

    // If group is not assigned returns default color
    public Color getColor() {
        return group != null ? group.getColor() : DEFAULT_COLOR;
    }

    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    // This way you will always have Person.group and Group.people in sync
    public void setGroup(Group newGroup) {
        if (group != newGroup) {
            if (group != null) {
                Group oldGroup = this.group;
                group = null;
                oldGroup.removePerson(this);
            }
            group = newGroup;
            if (newGroup != null) {
                newGroup.addPerson(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Group {
    private final List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    private Color color;

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        if (person != null) {
            people.add(person);
            person.setGroup(this);
        }
    }

    public void removePerson(Person person) {
        if (people.remove(person)) {
            person.setGroup(null);
        }
    }
}
```